# Cannot convert string to xmlelement

Tags: xml, web-services, powershell

Have the following script:

```
$query = "<CLAUSE OPER=""equals""><PROPERTY ID=""OrderForm.Status"" TYPE=""STRING"" MULTIVAL=""false"" /><IMMED-VAL TYPE=""STRING""><VALUE>Complete</VALUE></IMMED-VAL></CLAUSE>"
$queryxml = [xml]$query

$so = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1bService_OrdersWebService_asmx.SearchOptions
$so.NumberOfRecordsToReturn = 1

$req = $ws.SearchPurchaseOrders($queryxml,$so)
```

when executing, i get this error:

```
Cannot convert argument "searchClause", with value: "System.Xml.XmlDocument", for "SearchPurchaseOrders" to type "System.Xml.XmlElement": "Cannot convert the "System.Xml.XmlDocument" value 
of type "System.Xml.XmlDocument" to type "System.Xml.XmlElement"."
At line:10 char:1
+ $req = $ws.SearchPurchaseOrders($queryxml,$so)
```

nothing looks wrong with the xml. do i need a namespace or something?

Comment: `$queryxml` -> `$queryxml.DocumentElement`

Comment: thanks - that fixed it. why dont you put as answer?

Comment: I don't get the error in v5 but $so's TypeName doesn't look good at all to me and actually errors

    New-Object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1bService_OrdersWebService_asmx.SearchOptions]: verify 
that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

Comment: @JaquelineVanek As the namespace indicates, it's an autogenerated type (from `New-WebServiceProxy` by the looks of it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by error, `SearchPurchaseOrders` expect to get `XmlElement` but you passing `XmlDocument` and PowerShell can not convert that. You can use `DocumentElement` property to get root element of XML document:

```
$req = $ws.SearchPurchaseOrders($queryxml.DocumentElement,$so)
```